# Estimate for number of records in quartz tables

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am working on a Java/Java EE application that has 12 db tables and the same number of methods exposed via webservices. I have quartz configured to do some jobs to insert data in these tables via another operation. I am trying to estimate the number of records that would reside(maximum) in the quartz tables, i.e.

```
qrtz_blob_triggers
qrtz_calendars
qrtz_cron_triggers
qrtz_fired_triggers
qrtz_job_details
qrtz_locks
qrtz_paused_trigger_grps
qrtz_scheduler_state
qrtz_simple_triggers
qrtz_simprop_triggers
qrtz_triggers
```

I might not have given the complete information to arrive at a logical estimate. Please let me know if there is any other information that I can help with.

If somebody can at least provide me with an approach to arrive at an estimate that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on many factors. Generally, you can expect one record in the trigger tables for each job, assuming your implementation is correct and deleting a job also deletes the trigger. In job details you should have one set of records for each job. Scheduler state is implemenation dependant, too. These tables don't tend to be very large (unless you have a very large implementation with thousands of jobs). The log tables (assuming you write logs to the database) are the ones that get big.